# Determining the minimum number of edges to add to a graph to obtain a clique of size $k$

Tags: algorithms, graphs, reference-request, clique

As part of a [hobby project](https://cutonbuminband.github.io/counting-analysis/network.html#cliques) I stubmled into the following question which has me stumped:

Given an undirected graph $G = (V, E)$ and an integer $k$, what is that smallest number of edges that need to be added to $E$ such that the new graph $G' = (V, E')$ has a complete induced subgraph of size $k$, and what vertices would be involved?

I have never studied graph theory, so I wouldn't even know where to start with this problem. I can see the brute force solution which would be to look at all $\binom{|V|}{k}$ subsets of the vertices, and count how many of the $\frac{1}{2}k\cdot(k-1)$ necessary edges are already present in $G$. The subset with the smallest number of missing edges is the one I'm looking for. If we assume that $|V| \gg k$, that means looking at $\sim|V|^k$ subsets, and every edge of $E$. Is there a better way of doing things?

I have tried to see if anyone else has thought about this problem before, but I haven't found the right search terms. It seems that there's a class of problems known as graph editing problems, which I think this falls under, but I haven't been able to find anything when searching for that.

So, I fundamentally have two questions:

1. Does this problem have a name?
2. Is there a known solution that's better than brute force?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is called **Defective $k$-Clique** [[Yu et al.](https://doi.org/10.1093/bioinformatics/btl014), Bioinformatics (2006)].  The optimization problem is:

**Problem:** *Defective $k$-Clique*
**Input:** A graph $G$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
**Output:** The minimum number, $\ell$, of edges to add to $G$ such that $G$ has a $k$-clique.

Clearly, $G$ has a $k$-clique if and only if $\ell = 0$, hence the problem is NP-complete.  There is likely no algorithm running in time $f(k+\ell) \cdot n^{o(k + \ell)}$ [[Chen et al.](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ic.2005.05.001), Inf. Comput (2005)].  Hence, brute force seems like the only option.

That said, there's a difference between [brute forces (PDF)](https://folk.uib.no/nmiff/BookEA/BookEA.pdf).  You can [enumerate maximal cliques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)#Definitions), you can try to use [SAT solvers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAT_solver) or [ILP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming).  You can try with [branch & bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound), and [branch & reduce](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00138689) algorithms.  You can play around with [densest subgraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_subgraph)-algorithms, etc.  Don't give up hope of a practical algorithm just because theory says no.